# How can I run an Outlook macro in Python?

Tags: python, vba, outlook, win32com, office-automation

I would like to run an Outlook macro using Python.

This code and got nothing back:

```
import win32com.client
xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
xl.Application.Run("ExportUrlToTextFileFromEmail")
xl.Application.Quit()
xl=0
```

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide the `Application.Run` method like Excel does. Also you can't access Outlook macros using syntax like `Application.YourFunctionName` like other forum posts suggest doing.

You need to bring/convert your Outlook VBA code to a Python script.